# Update existing virtualenv to use Python 3.6

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have an existing virtualenv called 'edge'. It uses Python 3.5.2. I have upgrade my Python interpreter to 3.6 and I want the 'edge` env to use 3.6 instead.

What command should I used to `update` edge's interpreter?

I searched on SO but all the answers I can find are for creating a new env. In my case, I don't want to create a new env.

Comment: All binary packages installed for python3.5 are not compatible with python3.6 -- your best bet is to `edge/bin/pip freeze > reqs.txt && virtualenv edge2 -ppython3.6 && edge2/bin/pip install reqs.txt`

Comment: thx @AnthonySottile do you mind to write an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All binary packages installed for python3.5 (for example `numpy` or `simplejson`) are not compatible with python3.6 (they are not abi compatible).  As such, you can't upgrade / downgrade a virtualenv to a different version of python.

Your best bet would be to create a *new* virtualenv based on the packages installed in the original virtualenv.  You can get close by doing the following

```
edge/bin/pip freeze > reqs.txt
virtualenv edge2 -p python3.6
edge2/bin/pip install -r reqs.txt
```

Note that virtualenvs *generally* aren't movable, so if you want it to exist at `edge` you'll probably want the following procedure instead

```
edge/bin/pip freeze > reqs.txt
mv edge edge_old
virtualenv edge -p python3.6
edge/bin/pip install -r reqs.txt
# optionally: rm -rf edge_old
```

Comment: Python 3.6 recommend using:
python3 -m venv edge